# Change Certain Colors in a Texture in Java using OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, colors, textures, pixel

I need to be able to create a copy of a texture and change certain colors in that copy into other colors in java. I am not very fimiliar with the OpenGL library and I have no idea what methods it offers to do this. I need to know a good way to change the color of a single pixel in a texture and how to get the color of a single pixel in a texture, and also how to copy a texture. I'm sorry if this question is too broad, but I'm looking for a broad answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use glTexSubImage2D function to change the color of a single pixel in a texture. Below is the function header:

```
void glTexSubImage2D( GLenum target, GLint level, GLint xoffset, 
GLint yoffset, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, 
GLenum type, const GLvoid *data);
```

Here:

- **target** Specifies the target texture.
- **level** Specifies the level-of-detail number. Level 0 is the base image
  level. Level n is the nth mipmap reduction image.
- **xoffset** Specifies a texel offset in the x direction within the
  texture array.
- **yoffset** Specifies a texel offset in the y direction within the
  texture array.
- **width** Specifies the width of the texture subimage.
- **height** Specifies the height of the texture subimage
- **format** Specifies the format of the pixel data.
- **type** Specifies the data type of the pixel data.

Reference: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml

AND

Below is a code snippet of how to use it I found in the website referenced at the bottom:

```
void updateTexture(const chip8& c8)
{   
    // Update pixels
    for(int y = 0; y < 32; ++y)     
        for(int x = 0; x < 64; ++x)
            if(c8.gfx[(y * 64) + x] == 0)
                screenData[y][x][0] = screenData[y][x][1] = screenData[y][x][2] = 0;    // Disabled
        else 
            screenData[y][x][0] = screenData[y][x][1] = screenData[y][x][2] = 255;  // Enabled

    // Update Texture
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 ,0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)screenData);

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glTexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0);     glVertex2d(0.0,           0.0);
        glTexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0);     glVertex2d(display_width, 0.0);
        glTexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0);     glVertex2d(display_width, display_height);
        glTexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0);     glVertex2d(0.0,           display_height);
    glEnd();
}
```

Reference: http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-draw-pixels-to-a-texture-opengl/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to copy a texture is with `glCopyTexImage2D()`. This allows you to copy the content of the current framebuffer to a texture. If you want to use another texture as the source, you can set that texture as the content of a framebuffer object (FBO).

Let's say you already have a texture with name `srcTexId` that you want to use as the source of your copy operation. Now, you need to create a new texture for your destination first, which we will call `dstTexId`:

```
GLuint dstTexId = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &dstTexId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dstTexId);
glTexParameteri(...);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

Note the use of `NULL` for the last argument. This means that the texture content is allocated with the given format/size, but the texture is not filled with data.

Now we need an FBO, and set it up with the source texture as the content:

```
GLuint fbo = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D srcTexId, 0);
```

Everything is ready to perform the copy now:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dstTexId);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 0, 0, width, height, 0);
```

Then you can clean up your bindings if you like to keep the state undisturbed:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Another option to copy a texture is `glBlitFramebuffer()`. To use it, you would create two FBOs, one for reading and one for writing. So it requires a bit more setup, but it's also more flexible. For example, it allows you to resize (scale) the content as part of the copy, which is not supported with `glCopyTexImage2D()`.

To modify parts of a texture after you created the copy, use `glTexSubImage2D()`.

Comment: I forgot to specify: I'm using java.